Error Bradcom NIC BCM5719 Ubuntu 24.04 Time Out
i have a problem with a NIC Broadcom, in the journalctl send this messages
[353573.390021] tg3 0000:01:00.3 enp1s0f3: NETDEV WATCHDOG: CPU: 11: transmit queue 0 timed out 8829 ms [353573.390155] tg3 0000:01:00.3 enp1s0f3: transmit timed out, resetting [353574.788243] tg3 0000:01:00.3: tg3_stop_block timed out, ofs=1400 enable_bit=2 [353574.889990] tg3 0000:01:00.3: tg3_stop_block timed out, ofs=c00 enable_bit=2 [353574.965008] tg3 0000:01:00.3 enp1s0f3: Link is down [353577.193424] tg3 0000:01:00.3 enp1s0f3: Link is up at 100 Mbps, half duplex [353577.193427] tg3 0000:01:00.3 enp1s0f3: Flow control is off for TX and off for RX [353577.193428] tg3 0000:01:00.3 enp1s0f3: EEE is disabled [369643.369466] tg3 0000:01:00.3 enp1s0f3: Management side-band traffic will be interrupted during phy settings change
root@maniff:~# ethtool -i enp1s0f2 driver: tg3 version: 6.8.0-45-generic firmware-version: FFV22.91.5 bc 5719-v1.45 expansion-rom-version: bus-info: 0000:01:00.2 supports-statistics: yes supports-test: yes supports-eeprom-access: yes supports-register-dump: yes supports-priv-flags: no
root@maniff:~# lspci |grep net 01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01) 01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01) 01:00.2 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01) 01:00.3 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5719 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe (rev 01) 06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe 06:00.1 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries NetXtreme BCM5720 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe
root@maniff:~# uname -a Linux maniff 6.8.0-45-generic #45-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 30 12:02:04 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
This only happens when a lot of traffic is sent through the network interface, any ideas?
